# Host has single interface with 2 addresses, iptables SNAT for LXC containers to specific destination is not working

Tags: iptables, lxc

I need your help with iptables on Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.15.0-112-generic :

I have hosts that run a bunch of LXC containers, not using bridging over the hosts' LAN interface `lan1`, but each LXC container has its own IP addr.
The hosts have an IP addr from the range 10.101.22.0/25 which is routable in the company's internal network, and another IP addr from the range 192.168.202.0/23 which is NOT routable in the company's internal network. A snippet from `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` :

```
lan1:
  dhcp4: no
  dhcp6: no
  interfaces: [ bond0 ]
  parameters:
    stp: no
  addresses: [ 10.101.22.13/25, 192.168.203.244/23 ]
  gateway4: 10.101.22.1
```

And `ip a` output:

```
6: lan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 1e:11:24:59:86:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.101.22.13/25 brd 10.101.22.127 scope global lan1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.203.244/23 brd 192.168.203.255 scope global lan1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The LXC containers are supposed to communicate only with other addresses in the VLAN 192.168.202.0/23

This is working fine, no routing is needed from the LXC containers to anywhere else in the company.

Except... now I want the containers to reach anyhow an internal reverse proxy 10.125.11.215 to the Ubuntu mirrors, but their non-routed IP addresses 192.something will be rejected by that reverse proxy.
So I want the packets from the containers to the reverse proxy, being SNATted by the host's 10.101.22.13 source address.

I tried with the `iptables` command to add a POSTROUTING snat :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o lan1 -d 10.125.11.215/32 -s 192.168.202.0/23 -j SNAT --to-source 10.101.22.13
```

The output of `iptables -t nat -L -n`:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       all  --  192.168.202.0/23     10.125.11.215        to:10.101.22.13
```

But any traffic from such a container (which has IP=192.168.203.3, for example) to reach the reverse proxy on 10.125.11.215:80 is still not being SNATted, as shown by `tcpdump`:

```
# tcpdump -i lan1 -n host 10.125.11.215
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lan1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:21:47.791330 IP 192.168.203.3.8060 > 10.125.11.215.80: Flags [S], seq 1837832169, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3312729000 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:21:48.799250 IP 192.168.203.3.8060 > 10.125.11.215.80: Flags [S], seq 1837832169, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3312730007 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

The packets-count is also showing that none of these packets are treated by the POSTROUTING chain:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 144 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      lan1    192.168.202.0/23     10.125.11.215        to:10.101.22.13
```

What is missing?

thx a lot in advance!

Rob

Comment: Forgot to confirm that IPv4 forwarding is enabled: "cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" returns "1"

Comment: I don't think iptables knows what to do because your network definition is, possibly, incorrect. You need to define two network interfaces, one for each sub-net.

Comment: thx for the suggestion; altough network wise this setup of 2 addresses on a single network interface is very much correct, it could be that iptables does not know how to handle such configuration. I will try to migrate a first server host towards two network interfaces (one per subnet) and see if this helps iptables. Stay tuned ... ;-)

Comment: This does not seem to work: our host servers are configured with physical NICs and bonding over these NICs, then a bridge on top of such bond. The only documentation that I found to get two separate bridges with each one his own IP addr, describe to setup a stacked NIC/bond/vlan/bridge configuration with tagged-VLANs. But our network switches are not configured with VLAN-tagging. Consequently my bridges can't receive nor send any packets when they sit on top of NIC/bond/VLANs, even when I try to 'cheat' by setting "id: 0" in the VLan entries of my netplan file.